# Remote javascript html code injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, api

I wanted to verify whether my idea is correct - I would like to have script hosted on external server. I want to give user piece of java script code to insert into his website, which will call this external script and based on parameter included in request retrieve piece of another js custom code. This code should be also executed by the browser.

Is it possible ? If so, can that be done with asynchronous call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly how ALOT of 3rd party trackers and providers do it. A good example of this is [Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) by Google. You will see that they are doing exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to google how to write such script but with no luck, any clue which keywords should I use while googling?

Answer (score 1):

How about calling an external link passing a parameter (GET or POST) and then this url will return the script url based on the parameter you used? That should be something doable for your case. As MattSizzle suggested above, lots of 3rd party things do things like that. Also, a script can make an ajax call and get data or what you need.

Hop that helps!